# Point out that bounties are non-refundable

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties

[Plenty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97001/getting-bounty-offer-back) of [people](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64074/i-want-my-bounty-back) [inquire](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164597/how-will-we-get-back-our-reputation-when-we-set-the-bounty-and-we-find-answer-by) on Meta about getting their bounty back; the latest case was [today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165812/why-dont-bounties-give-you-reputation-back-automatically-if-you-answer-the-ques).

I was surprised to find that there is indeed no mention of bounties' non-refundability during the actual process.

Yeah, yeah, people should read the FAQ and all that, but it seems fair (and trivially easy) to mention the fact briefly. Please add something like

[image]

Comment: But...but..I don't want to refund them. I just want to award them to my own answer.

Comment: If my memory serves me right, there used to be an `alert` which popped up when you were going to finalize the bounty reminding you of this. Is it still there?

Comment: @Tim good point! Just tried it out, it's not there any more (at least not on Meta). I'll be happy to test on SO if anybody can think of a question that deserves a bounty

Comment: I'm with @Bart - especially given the fact I'm the only person who even managed to answer!

Comment: Please note that my comment was largely tongue-in-cheek @SteveFenton, hinting that users would still come to Meta in surprise. I did in fact vote this proposal up.

Comment: Sorry Steve, my response above was complete nonsense. I took your comment to be a response to an entirely different conversation about bounties where I disagreed with @Bart.

Comment: Which is of course nonsense as well @Pekka웃....disagreeing with me....tsk tsk tsk.

Comment: @Bart IT'S A WAY OF LIFE MAN

Comment: Now I feel like I've missed out because I never saw the comment :)

Comment: @Steve heh! It said something like "If you managed to give an answer, why would the OP deny you the bounty?" It seemed like a continuation of the argument we were having here: [Explicit "do not award bounty" button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166172)

Comment: Yeah. That makes no sense here. I'm starting a new topic `Why don't people read comments properly before responding?` :)

Comment: NOOOO!!!! I was testing

Answer (score 10):

Apparently we implemented this... Back in June of 2013.

[image: this reputation is deducted immediately and cannot be refunded]

Kudos to PythonMaster for using a bounty to remind me to status-complete this.

[image: djasjdaksldsjadsadsadadaswWWWW]

djasjdaksldsjadsadsadadaswWWWW to you too, PythonMaster; djasjdaksldsjadsadsadadaswWWWW to you too.

Comment: I would like a compensation for my efforts

Comment: If you post a good answer, you could earn a hat...

Comment: ... or a bounty. You never know.

Comment: At least I got a hat :)