# In what cases does a user get 5 reputation points for an up-vote on an answer?

Tags: support, up-votes, daily-reputation-limit

I am looking at [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166172/explicit-do-not-award-bounty-button/166216#166216), and checked what other up-votes the user got on [the profile page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/141525/animuson?tab=reputation), and noticed a 5 reputation up-vote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Animuson nearly had hit the rep cap before that 5-point vote. He had already reached 195 points from upvotes by that point.

You can only ever earn 200 points in a day for upvotes on both questions and answers, but question upvotes only earn you 5 points at a time. 19 answer upvotes + 1 question upvotes totalled to 195, so the final answer upvote was capped to 5 points only to round up his reputation increase to 200.