# Can I avoid awarding the bounty out?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties, accepted-answer, community

So in the same vein that accepting an answer does, awarding bounties should follow, more or less, the same logic.

When a user accepts an answer, they do so because whatever was in that answer helped them out the most, or worked for them the best, etc.

When a user awards a bounty, they do so not to help fill sockpuppets, but they do so because they believe the answer they awarded it too deserves it.  Either because its content is in-depth and thorough, maybe the awarder likes the points they bring up, etc.

Now, I have a dilemna. I have a question that has a bounty I place on it in which I find NO answers to help my situation. The answers, I feel, are just excuses in regards to the question I asked.  Now, I'm aware that if I don't award the bounty, the bounty will be split up amongst the two highest scoring answers above +2 net votes.  In this case, both answers (of which there are only 2), are way above +2.

I don't want to award a bounty to a post I feel does not deserve it. In the same way a user asking question will not accept an answer that does not help them, bounties should do the same.

In some instances, the community will overwhelmingly upvote an answer way beyond the accepted answer, but the notion is, the OP doesn't just select the answer with the most votes, but that helped HIS/HER situation.  So in that sense, why can't bounties be the same? Just because the community deems an answer particularly helpful doesn't mean it helps the person who issued the bounty.

Is there any way to avoid awarding the bounty out? Obviously, the rep will not be returned to me; otherwise, that could lead to gaming the system and w/e.

Comment: [Explicit “do not award bounty” button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166172/explicit-do-not-award-bounty-button)

Comment: @animuson too bad nothing in that thread was actually added as a feature

Comment: Just pointing it out. Your question is technically a support request. But if you want to make it a feature request, it's a duplicate of that question.

Comment: The bounty is not being split up amongst the highest scoring answers, half of the bounty is given to one single answer which was posted during the bounty period and has the highest score, of at least 2. Not really relevant to  your request, just saying. :)

Comment: Wait, your only bounty that I can find so far is *here on Meta* and none of the answers there are new enough to qualify for auto-awarding. If you do nothing, the bounty will go poof automatically. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, no system exists to revoke a bounty once it is placed. If the question has answers with over +2, then the bounty must be awarded in some capacity.

Apologies, but this just isn't the way the bounty system is set up right now.

Comment: Bounty definitely needs a rework. Just because of the question I am tempted to make an answer and award it to myself; despite me not gaining any reputation, only because I do not like any of the answers posted, and thus feel they do not deserve any bounty

Comment: I can guarantee this would not be received well by the community, and I would strongly recommend not doing this.

Comment: Right, hence why I stated "I am tempted".  The system is flawed so that I am forced to award it to answers with sufficient votes; despite the fact I find the answers lacking. Making the bounty completely useless, because the bounty is an "incentive" for helping the OP out, not because of a community-supported answer.

Comment: @euphoriaoverlord You cannot award a bounty to yourself anyways. It's not possible.