# How to un-auto-award a bounty to an answer that didn't solve my problem?

Tags: support, bounties

I recently received a message telling me "Your bounty on question "[How to dynamically inject a service using a runtime "qualifier" variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42909283/how-to-dynamically-inject-a-service-using-a-runtime-qualifier-variable)" has expired - answer auto-selected."

But how can that be? None of the answers truly solved my problem, especially because I had to develop a workaround to finally have what I wanted.

And now 25 points have been given to an answer that didn't serve my purpose? Seriously?!

How do I undo this?

Comment: It's all explained in [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: The discussion [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166172/explicit-do-not-award-bounty-button) will probably be interesting to you.

Comment: Also [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/54998/195817#97802) and [these related questions](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/54998).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bounty is cash money you give to the bank once you start it.

The bank keeps it and you get to choose who will get it. If you do not choose, the bank itself gets to choose. Once you started the bounty aka gave the reputation, it's no longer yours.

There is no way to undo a bounty that was already awarded, even for moderators.

Comment: `There is no way to undo a bounty that was already awarded, even for moderators.` Sure there is; the post can be deleted (which a moderator would be able to do).  Of course, a moderator isn't going to delete an answer just because the OP doesn't like it, but if it merited deletion, the bounty would be reversed.

Comment: OK, thanks for your explanation. That should prevent me from using this in the future.

Comment: @Servy this isn't really undoing the bounty, and as you said moderator isn't going to delete answer just because OP think it didn't deserve the bounty. Having score of 2 or more means it's not a bad answer.

Comment: @maxxyme your choice, nobody is forcing anyone to use bounties

Comment: And if you give money to a homeless person so he can buy some food, and he spends it on alcohol, you have no recourse.  And if you lend money to a friend or relative so he can pay his rent, and he uses it to take a vacation, you have no recourse.  … … … …  Also: … … … …  “Having score of 2 or more means it’s not a bad answer.”  Are you serious?  Having score of 2 or more hopefully means it’s probably not a terrible answer.

Comment: @Scott on smaller sites score of 2 is rare and yes it means the answer is good. Since this is MSE, it's about all sites. Agree that on SO in popular tags, +2 is nothing. As for what people do with the money they get as charity can't see how it's related?

Comment: Your answer says that, once you pay your money to the “bank”, the “bank” may do things with that money that you don’t like.  I believe that the analogy is obvious.  Perhaps a better one:  you buy an advertisement saying you want somebody to paint your house.  You get no serious responses, but some guy with some cans of spray paint comes along and puts some urban art on your domicile.  If two people like it, the advertising agency gives your money to the graffiti artist.

Answer (score 4):

If you didn't award even till the end of grace period, the bounty winning answer may be selected under some criteria.

**They are**

- The answer with score 2 or more
- if more than one answer match the criteria, the oldest one will be chosen.
- half of the bounty amount will be awarded.
- If that is also the accepted answer, then the full bounty will be awarded.

To remove the bounty earned, the answer should be deleted.

#### In you case

There are 2 answer with 2 upvotes each.

So, the oldest one will be chosen.

Now the only solution is to flag for mod which they may not agree to delete.

In future,
If you don't want to award the bounty to any of the answer, if the answer have only 2 upvotes, then **If the answer didn't solved your problem**, cast a downvote. at the end of grace period, if the answer didn't have atleast 2 upvotes, it won't be eligible for bounty.

Comment: No. Downvoting is **not** a good choice to avoid the bounty being auto awarded.... that's not what downvotes are for. Just because the answer doesn't work for the OP doesn't mean it's a bad answer in general.

Comment: @Catija I know downvotes are not good. But OP's question is specific. So, the answer doesn't work means it is a bad answer. For that purpose only I bolded **In your case** and **if the answer didn't solved your problem**