# What should I do when the bounty expired but none of the answers really solves the problem?

Tags: support, bounties, expired-bounty

I have this question on Stack Overflow with a bounty that expired a few hours ago:

[WCAG: Firefox and Edge don't show outline on focussed input elements when styles are applied](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51674380/2711071)

---

Currently there are multiple answers, which:

- are all right in their saying
- are basically all the same
- *don't answer the question*

To make the last point clear:

> The question is not about how CSS work or how browsers differ in the way they render elements by default.

The question bascially is:

> How to comply with a WCAG recommendation which says: Maintain a certain behavior (not alter it) across different OS' and browsers but still be able to change CSS?

---

By now [a late answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51816355/2711071) got three upvotes, even though it just repeats what was answered earlier. This answer is now eligible for an auto-award.

The [first answerer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51676475/2711071), put a lot of effort into this issue through a discussion in the comments, even though the answer doesn't directly addresses the problem.

---

To make my point a bit clearer here are some examples I'm looking for plus official citation or working examples - as I'm unable to provide enough real world test cases with people in this scenario:

> Change the focus indicator the way you want it. If there's a custom one by the OS all browser will still overwrite your custom one.

or

> This is not achievable across all OS's and browsers, because …

or

> Just use a good own indicator and skip this WCAG recommendation, because …

---

My questions are now:

- Can I prevent the auto-awarding?

or:

- Should I manually award the first answer, because the discussion was helpful, even though, the answer itself doesn't solve the issue and I'm not going to use the green checkmark on it?

---

Somewhere I read that it's possible to award half the bounty, but I couldn't find a way to do so.

---

I read [Explicit “do not award bounty” button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166172/explicit-do-not-award-bounty-button?newreg=3be97ae76ff6474da5455f0e881e748f) – but it is declined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I prevent the auto-awarding?

No.

> Should I manually award the first answer, because the discussion was helpful, even though, the answer itself doesn't solve the issue and I'm not going to use the green checkmark on it?

That's entirely your call to make.  That's the whole point of bounties, you can use whatever criteria you want for them.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I prevent the auto-awarding?

No, unless you award the full amount manually, or manage to get all answers' scores below 2.

> Should I manually award the first answer, because the discussion was helpful, even though, the answer itself doesn't solve the issue and I'm not going to use the green checkmark on it?

That's perfectly fine; nobody forces you to accept an answer. Nobody forces you to consciously award a bounty either.

> Somewhere I read that it's possible to award half the bounty, but I couldn't find a way to do so.

Nope, half the bounty only happens if it's automatically awarded.