# How do I dispute the auto-award of a bounty on a question on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, bounties

My question did not get a true answer. Half of my bounty was auto-awarded to an unhelpful answer. How do I dispute that?

Ref: *[Jenkins Declarative Pipeline - want to get path to Jenkinsfile in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51370984/jenkins-declarative-pipeline-want-to-get-path-to-jenkinsfile-in-use)*

Comment: BTW, it's impossible to know for me, but the first and foremost thing you should do when an answer does not address your question correctly is **downvote it**. Did you? In this case, it would have prevented the bounty from bring awarded, I think.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier the answer has no down votes  at the moment. It got an upvote the day the answer got posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't; the bounty allows you to get attention - it doesn't guarantee an acceptable answer. [The rules for auto-awarding](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) exist to ensure that bounties are awarded if at all possible; this helps encourage folks to seek them out and give them attention... But again, it does not and cannot make any guarantees as to the value of that attention.

As always, the best way to get a useful answer is to make your question as clear and specific as possible.

#### See also: [Explicit "do not award bounty" button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166172/explicit-do-not-award-bounty-button)