# Revisit - Allow a bounty to go un-awarded. No winner

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, bounties

I'm raising this again because I now have a question I would dearly like to find an answer to, with one totally wrong answer awarded a bounty. I would prefer to be able to delete the entire question rather than leave this wrong answer as the only thing users will see if they visit it.

Relating to *[Please do not auto select answers on bounty questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4508/please-do-not-auto-select-answers-on-bounty-questions)* which is marked `[status-complete]` and *[Explicit "do not award bounty" button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166172/explicit-do-not-award-bounty-button) which is marked* `[status-declined]`.

The answers to the latter do not answer the question as asked. They are all essentially frame challenges, or reasons why variations on this theme have not worked in the past.  E.g., a bounty is a payment for advertising. That is not an answer. The payment has been made, and the advertising has been gained. If I paid for an advert for a job opportunity I would certainly not be bound to offer the job to the least worst candidate. I could choose… none.

Therefore this is a new question with a clear goal.

I want to decide if no one deserves the bounty.
It should not be tied to votes, accepted check marks or who answered at what time. There is no gain for the user who offered the bounty. That's already gone, given away at the start. If no satisfactory answer is received, the bounty should not be awarded automatically without giving the initiator the chance to say no. If no action is taken you can assume lack of interest and auto-award. If a definitive action is taken, that should be the right of the one whose reputation was staked on receiving a satisfactory solution.

A decade later and this is still **badly broken**, IMO.

I should have the right to decide no one deserves the bounty. The bounty should not be a reward for effort but a reward for getting the answer right!

I offered a 500-point bounty on a new question right from the start, to pull some attention to an issue I knew was going to be tough to answer.
*[The volume is the wrong format for a backup. Why?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/421062/the-volume-is-the-wrong-format-for-a-backup-why)*

As expected, no one even got close, though one answer received three upvotes… perhaps for effort. The answer went through three major revisions, none of which were salient and after a comment thread 22 deep trying to clarify, the last version was still totally wide of the mark.
Two answers were deleted, for not even leaving the starting blocks.

This question itself also went through some major revisions, reducing some initial guesswork as my endeavour to find a single underlying symptom/cause was honed. Also, in each revision was an attempt to clarify what was confusing the answerers and commenters… not that it seemed to make any real difference to misinterpretations.

The end result, however, was there was no answer anywhere near.
This means, in my mind, **no one deserves the bounty.**

I want the option to declare specifically that **no one gets the bounty**. However, the system automatically gave half points to the one remaining answer, with little regard as to how well it actually answered the question.

I have already given up the points. I don't want them back; I just feel no one deserved them. I should have been given that choice.

I didn't upvote any of the answers. None of them were more than misreadings of the question, or very poor guesses. I didn't downvote anyone either - I decided the users should decide, until and unless I got a working solution, which would then have been marked accepted and also awarded the bounty. I have in the past awarded bounties without accepting, for answers which showed good research and working method, or a good path towards a 'fix' even if it didn't work in my particular case.

Comment: The thing is, you've used the bounty to its fullest, and that is all that matters. It shouldn't really matter to you who gained from it, no?

Comment: @AnnZenat1YearAnniversary Sure... it can matter - it indicates that the answer is somehow worthy of special recognition. If that's not the case it ends up with the answer looking better than it is. The one thing that makes this less concerning is that it's awarded by Community rather than the bounty offerer - but many people don't bother checking.

Comment: My primary concern with the request here is the potential for abuse from some - choosing to intentionally refuse to award the bounty, even when the answers are worthy. It's a difficult balance to strike and I'm not sure that making this change makes the situation better. I do understand your concerns but I also feel like (in most cases) the need for a score of 3 *usually* prevents low-quality answers from receiving the bounty when they shouldn't.

Comment: @Catija - I do understand the concern - though there really ought to be an element of trust in someone already of sufficient rep to be in a position to offer a bounty. I'd hate to suggest the option should only be available to 10k+ rep or something. As it turns out, though, rather than leaving it to 'the users' I could have in this case, in effect, refused the bounty by down-voting. Had I known that, I would have. Too late now, of course. [repost to fix typo]

Comment: Given the history of this feature, it is not something that is ever going to change over time. The answer is no.

Comment: I don't agree (or disagree) with the request but Catija's concern is valid. Some users _will_ ask follow-up questions, either in the comments or by editing the question, and threaten to not award the bounty if you don't offer "extra help". This already happens with the "accept" feature and I predict it will also happen with bounties.

Comment: @Rob - last edit removed. Back to what if I advertise a job where I am **compelled** to accept one candidate, whether or not they are suitable for that job. I will never again advertise a job. I will never again pay to advertise for someone I do not wish to employ.

Comment: One more thing: _"The bounty should not be a reward for effort..."_ Maybe you're right and maybe not; I think this is debatable. _"...but a reward for getting the answer right"_ **No**, you should _accept_ an answer that gets it right (or the most one that does) but give the bounty to the most helpful one (at least in my opinion). More than once, I've given the **full amount** of bounties to answers that I didn't accept because although they were, they didn't directly solve my problem.

Comment: @41686d6564 - I've already stated in the question [why do people not read the question - this is why I raised this in the first place!] I do this if an answer is worthy. I still retain the right to not offer if no answer is worthy. In the absence of that 'right' I shall simply not use that service again. I do not want to reward poor answers.

Comment: Response to [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366154/re-visit-allow-a-bounty-to-go-un-awarded-no-winner#comment1219891_366154): `... what if I advertise a job where I am compelled to accept one candidate, [regardless]. I will never again advertise a job. I will use other means, word of mouth, or Google.` --- Your *compulsion* to hire is: advertising costs, time that could have been better used, plus you lose a person who could bring in X dollars per day and likely not be paid 10% that much. - Employees have blogs / WOM too; who has the most to lose. Hire, pay **$+** or close.

Comment: @Rob - why on earth would I hire someone unsuitable? I would in the real world advertise again - which is what I would have done in this instance had I not been **compelled** to reward an unsuitable candidate. Your reasoning is unsound.

Comment: @Tetsujin You are, of course, entitled to your own decision but I would say think about it this way... after you offer a bounty, the rep points are no longer yours. If the community decides to vote on an answer making it reach a particular score, that's on the community, not you. It's just like upvotes, except that the vote has more "weight" in that case. Perhaps raising the threshold (as suggested in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166172/explicit-do-not-award-bounty-button#comment485945_166174)) is something worth discussing.

Comment: _"why on earth would I hire someone unsuitable"_ But you didn't. The community (by voting) and the community user (by having their name associated with the bounty) are the ones who did.

Comment: As OP & bounty-giver, I am the only person qualified to decide whether the answer was even vaguely pertinent to my question. That the community didn't read it properly either is really not my issue. they jumped to 'big obvious' without wondering whether it was correct. It wasn't. Two major revisions later it still showed they hadn't actually read the question. The two deleted answers, one would have destroyed the data I was trying to preserve, the other should have been a comment & didn't attempt to answer.

Comment: *...what if I advertise a job where I am compelled to accept one candidate...* But that's not what's happening here. You aren't awarding half the bounty, the site is. This is more like you paying to advertise for a job and then trying to tell the newspaper or job site what to do with the money after you've spent it. It's eating a steak at a restaurant and then, instead of refusing to pay outright, telling the manager the cook shouldn't get any of the money because it was overcooked.

Comment: @41686d6564 Re 'This already happens with the "accept" feature': the abuse of the accept feature does not lead to the feature being changed (into auto-accept, which would be an equivalent of the bounty implementation). The reason is probably that such abuse does not happen often. Similarly the current proposal has merit, but also carries a small risk of abuse. To determine the risk more precisely, SE could run an experiment for a few months for example, instead of just declining it without further consideration.

Comment: @Marijn I agree that the request might have merit. That's why I stated earlier that I neither agree nor disagree with it (I don't have a strong opinion in either direction). That said, the difference between the bounty auto-award and the "accept" feature is that the latter is a strong indication that the OP (and only the OP) considers the answer to be correct. The OP's name is associated with it. That problem does not exist with bounty auto-award. As I said above, who awards the bounty, in that case, is the community (by voting) and the community user (by having their name associated with it).

Comment: Looking at this over a year later; my initial opinion has not changed, but I have recently raised a bounty [first time since this event, as far as I can recall]. *This* time, though I'm advertising for 'more answers' there is already an answer I am perfectly willing to award the bounty to, should no-one better it. I retain control in this instance.

Answer (score 10):

While I understand the feeling of not wanting to see bounties on answers that you feel don't deserve it and seeing the price you paid for advertising your question not pay off the way you want to, I have some doubts when it comes to allowing people to just *not* award a bounty, because you're not the only party involved here: There's also the person that spends their time in an attempt to answer. For the automatic awarding of half a bounty, a third party enters the fray: The people that see the existing answer and vote on that as having some merit, instead of writing their own.

Now, you could argue that bounty hunters are the worst, and I would probably be able to commiserate to some extent. But this answer you got (I've read it, even though I don't understand much of it) doesn't seem like someone just out there for some quick win. This person stuck with their answer, and seems to have made an actual effort to edit their answer to make it as useful as possible. From their side, it would probably feel like someone dangling a carrot in front of your face, and then taking it away.

There's just no pleasing everyone, and I like the current system for splitting the bounty in half, and awarding half of it under the Community user's name. Your name no longer is on the bounty so anyone can see you weren't satisfied. At the same time, awarding half of it takes away some of the feeling that someone was just dangling a carrot in front of you.

If there really are too many bounties that end up auto-awarded because of the score of two votes for it (perhaps someone can actually get numbers on how often this happens?), it might be time to ask for raising that threshold. But please keep the current 50/50 system

Comment: _"bounties that end up auto-awarded because of the three votes needed for it"_ Did you mean _two_ upvotes or are you taking into account that OP (or whoever offered the bounty) will most likely downvote in that situation?

Comment: If I understand this answer correctly, the only problem with the feature is that someone could put a bounty, and then not award it to an eligible answer, right? In that case, maybe enable the 50/50 system _only_ for the low rep users with no history of bounties, and _enable_ the feature for higher rep users who can be trusted.

Comment: Since the bounty was auto-awarded, I downvoted that answer, so for low-rep users it now shows as just +2. If you look at my last edit to the question, I have now offered a retrospective bounty to anyone who does find it later & provides a good answer. That's the best I can do now, in the circumstances. I will certainly never offer one up again proactively, because it doesn't work. No matter how much "effort" the answerer put in, he never grasped the point, nor ever properly read the question. Each response had already been covered in the question, so the answer actually added nothing at all.

Comment: @41686d6564 good catch. I automatically went with three because that was the score mentioned in a comment under the question. My bad! I've corrected that.

Comment: @10Rep you should post that as a seperate feature request :)

Comment: Well said. To add: if the answer was truly bad, it would eventually be deleted, which would revoke the bounty rep gain anyway.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog - the answer wasn't 'truly bad' - in fact it was good enough to fool 3 people into thinking it was actually a helpful answer to the question. My point is still that even after 3 revisions, the author giving up at that point, it still was making assumptions *already clarified* in the question. It has now a big blue badge promoting it as 'worthy of a bounty'… which it wasn't.