# How can I forcibly remove a question with no answers from the Bountied list?

Tags: support, bounties

If a question with bounty has an answer, you can award the bounty to that answer and that will remove the question from the [Bountied list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=bounties).

Is it possible to remove the question (before the bounty is expired) from the Bountied list if there's no answer? With no help from a moderator, obviously.

I'm not asking for refund, I'm asking about the removing from the bounty list.

Comment: No that's not possible and it's good. Can't see any valid reason to do such a thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>As far as I misunderstood the question at first, you have now explicitly stated that refund isn’t something you’re interested in, so I may now be able to answer it.</sup>

Indeed, there's no possible way to just silently remove a bounty without a help of mod, without awarding it to any answer, before it runs out itself.

Let's break down possible scenarios of *why you would you ever want* to nuke a bounty before its expiration date:

1. **You believe that you have found the answer yourself**. But this doesn't exactly allow you do dispose neither of bounty, nor of the question itself. There have been disputes on meta regarding that, every now and then there're users who just want to censor out anything in their post once they found an answer, but that's not how Stack Exchange works - [the posts here aren't owned by you but merely licensed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18226/259214).
2. **You believe that your question is not suitable for the site, but it has got a bounty**. Flagging an unsalvageable post for moderator intervention is most straightforward here, although a non-severe case [you can just wait for a bounty to run out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308724/2963652) and close then. The last one may actually constitute for a refund.
3. **You believe that your question is just generally a bad question in a way you didn't realize before**. That's what happened to me once: I asked a fundamentally wrong question as a starting web-developer 8-9 years ago. But everybody makes mistakes, you're not getting punished for that other than with downvotes. And if the post is really absolutely horrible, you can delete it and request it to be deleted, that's also what happened to me 8-9 years ago.
4. **You believe that this post defaces you in some way you didn't realize before**. This is definitely a more severe case of the previous point. If that's true, I think that you can just request for the [post to be unlinked from your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa).
5. **You suddenly noticed that there's some sensitive information**. This applies to any question, not only a bountied one. Flag a moderator to request a redaction, and probably as well @poke someone somewhere if the issue looks to be urgent. I really doubt it's your case but leaving this point for completeness.

Apart from these scenarios, I can't think of any other reason you would ask such a question. In all the other cases I believe you could just leave a bounty for a Community user to decide whom to award or not award at all, check section *"What happens if I feel my question is still unanswered? / What is automatic awarding?"* [in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/259214).

There was a request to [introduce "don't want to award at all" button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166172/explicit-do-not-award-bounty-button?rq=1) but this was declined.

Answer (score 6):

No, this is not possible. Only ♦ moderators can remove bounties, and doing so refunds the bounty amount to the user who posted the bounty, so this is only done in rare circumstances and usually not upon request by the bounty poster. From the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/295232):

> Part of what you're "paying for" with a bounty is for higher question visibility and increased answerer motivation. A bounty does **not** guarantee a response and is **not refunded** if none are received.

Having an active bounty is equivalent to being on the Bountied list, there's no option to opt out from it.

Comment: I believe it’s worth just closing the question as a dupe of faq instead since even in the [bounty pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZgl1.jpg) the obvious is stated

Comment: @nicael I'm not asking for refund, I'm asking about the removing from the bounty list.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ hm, makes sense

Answer (score -3):

Not tried by self, and I think it's against the site rules, and actually violate the OP condition about not having an answer, but...

It's look technically possible to post an answer as a sock puppet and assign the bounty to it. That will remove the question from the bounty list. Of course the [time to award the bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386378/339911) must be achieved before.

Comment: Clever, but then you're doing something you cannot do with a single account, which is the [ground rule for determining acceptable sockpuppet behaviour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685/295232).

Comment: "post an answer as a sock puppet and assign the bounty to it" - great way to get suspended. Voting to delete this dangerous answer. If you want to get suspended then great, have fun, but don't take others with you!!

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars why do you think that absence of information is better than the information marked as violating rules?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but what you suggest is against the rules and might lead to suspension. Pretty much like saying to someone "If you need money, then steal it".

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars and the post will be returned to bounties list by the mod then?

Comment: No, it will not, even mod can't do that. If it's worth for you to get a suspension over something like that then like I already said, go ahead. But don't suggest others to follow your illegal actions as well, keep it to yourself please.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars we are all mature people here, but it seems that your desire to delete a post looks for me like the parental mode. What you are doing is pure censorship.