# No tooltip or any other info why the bounty is not awardable for immature bounty on iPad

Tags: bug, bounties, accessibility, ipad, ios

Before the bounty gets mature (allowed to award) on desktop browser or even on Android I can see the tooltip:

> [image: Desktop Chrome]

Android 13 Chrome (touch screen) after tapping on the icon:

> [image: Android Chrome]

But I can't see any tooltip or notifications on iPad (iPadOS 16.2 Google Chrome) while I'm tapping on grey +50 icon.

> [image: iPadOS Chrome]

I even tried with connected mouse (expecting the tooltip will be showed on mouse over or click), but no luck:

> [image: with attached mouse]

---

*You may have thought* that these are tooltips that come with Chrome, however Stack Exchange appears to have its own tooltipping mechanism, here's what you get if you inspect a tooltip:

[image]

Which means that the behavior can be tweeked on the stack-exchange-side and doesn't really depend on standard tooltip implementation in browsers.

For accessibility reason I think some kind of notification must be available while tapping on the grey +50 icon. Instead it looks like something broken on the page.

Comment: Touch devices have no tooltip, it's a known issue and not related to Stack Exchange.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars It's exist on Android as I said.

Comment: I believe it actually doesn’t, that’s rather a chrome’s own adaptation of tooltipping mechanism for touch devices that does have nothing to do with SE

Comment: @nicael as I said above, I can see the tooltip on Android touch screen device. Please look at screenshot in the question.

Comment: @sha whoops! looks like those tooltips are [custom stack exchange tooltips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwoMy.png), so this issue can still be fixed nonetheless for accessibility reasons at least. So I'm taking back my words: that's not chrome tool tipping mechanism, and thus behavior can potentially be tweaked